# given point lies inside or outside a polygon

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I was trying this question and found a solution :

Draw a horizontal line to the right of each point and extend it to infinity

```
1) Count the number of times the line intersects with polygon edges.
2) A point is inside the polygon if either count of intersections is odd or point lies on an edge of polygon.If none of the conditions is true, then point lies outside.
```

[image]

But i think there is a simple solution to this :

```
for(all sides in same order)
find vector product of the 3 points (given point and end points of each side)
```

> if all products are > or < 0 : point lies inside polygon or on boundary
>   else outside

`isn't my solution better and efficient ?
is there another simpler algorithm than this ?`

Comment: Your proposed solution doesn't work for convex polygons. Try it for point c in your figure.

Comment: I suggest you look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: A little irrelevant, but a cool solution to this (which is readily computable in o(#points)) is to regard c as a point in the complex plane and then calculate the line integral of $\frac{1}{1-c}$ along the polygon. The result will be zero iff c is inside the polygon, and this also works for self intersecting polygons.

Comment: hey should it be :`if sum of all products is +- 360 degree : point lies inside polygon or on boundary else outside`

Answer (score 2):

If I remember properly, join your point to all the points which define the polygon. Compute the sum of the angles. If they add up to 2 Pi, your point is inside the polygon.

Comment: This would be a solution if the polygon is convex. But if the polygon is non-convex, you may not be able to use the "sum of angles adding up to 2Pi" property.

Comment: Claude, are you familiar with the formula in the answer below?$$\;\oint H(x) \, \delta(y) \, dy = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint d\phi\;$$